# What was the point of this conversation between Megamind and Minion?

Tags: plot-explanation, megamind

In the 2010 animated movie *Megamind*, after seemingly killing his arch-nemesis Metro Man, Megamind finds himself without a purpose and decides to create a new superhero by infusing someone with Metro Man's DNA. After accidentally shooting and infusing Hal Stewart, the following discussion takes place between Megamind and Minion:

> **Megamind**: Who is this man we've infused with godlike power?
>
> **Minion** (using a laptop to obtain information): Well, sir, his name's Hal Stewart. He's 28 years old. No criminal record. Actually, no records at all. Apparently, this man hasn't accomplished anything.
>
> **Megamind**: Not yet, Minion. Not...yet.
>
> **Minion**: So I will just go ahead and defuse him, since this is clearly a mistake.

**My Questions**:

- Why did Minion think someone with a bad record should be infused with Metro Man's DNA while Megamind himself had cleared it that someone good should be shot and trained to become a new hero so that Megamind can fight in a battle of good vs evil?
- Why did Megamind reply to Minion with "not yet" when Minion said Hal Stewart hadn't committed any crimes in his life yet? Again, didn't Megamind himself tell Minion there should be a good person to fight him? Does fighting a bad person make a good person bad? Even if it makes a good person bad, that was never part of Megamind's plan. He just wanted to have a nemesis in order to not be without a purpose.

Comment: _"After **accidentally** shooting and infusing Hal Stewart"_ versus _"Why did Minion think someone with a bad record **should be** infused with Metro Man's DNA"_ Accidents are pretty much inherently defined as an event that was not explicitly wanted or expected.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's not the "No criminal records" part that Minion objects to. As you noted, that's a good thing. It's the next part that Minion objects to:

> Actually, no records at all. Apparently, **this man hasn't accomplished anything.**

So Hal hasn't done anything bad, but he hasn't done anything good, either (or at least, anything meaningful enough to have been recorded). Minion figures that if Hal hasn't accomplished anything *without* powers, then he's unlikely to accomplish anything *with* powers.

Similarly, when Megamind replies, "Not yet", he's responding to the "this man hasn't accomplished anything" part. What he means is "Hal hasn't accomplished anything *yet*" - now that he has Metro Man's powers, he's bound to accomplish *something*. Unfortunately, what he ends up accomplishing is the exact opposite of what Megamind intended for him to accomplish.

Answer (score 12):

Minion isn't saying that Hal is inappropriate due to having no criminal record. Minion's opinion is that Hal was infused by accident and they have no idea what sort of person he is, and therefore (considering the power they just infused him with) it would be safest to extract that power. Minion knows that human behaviour is unpredictable and that suddenly turning a random citizen into a superhero is a dicey proposition at best.

As the remainder of the movie shows, Hal is singularly unsuited to the god-like powers Megamind accidentally gave him, proving that Minion's caution was well-founded.

Megamind on the other hand is simply eager for a purpose again, and his poor understanding of human nature and behaviour is quite evident throughout the film. Megamind doesn't believe that a human invested with Metroman's power would be a danger. He is convinced that the new superhero would inevitably choose to use their powers for good. Hence his disbelief when Titan fails to show up to fight him and instead goes on a crime spree.